# Control dependencies in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the following behavior: When I run the code

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(0.0)
f = x*x

op0 = tf.assign_add(x, 1.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([op0]):
  op1 = tf.assign(y, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(op1)
  print(y.eval())
```

the result is sometimes `4.0` as I would expect, but sometimes it is `1.0`. The result of `1.0` indicates that the dependency `op0` was ignored. However, since I sometimes get `4.0`, `op0` must have been computed, which to my understanding could only have been triggered by the dependency.

If I do something similar, but without the tensor `f`, e.g,

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(0.0)

op0 = tf.assign_add(x, 1.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([op0]):
  op1 = tf.assign(y, x) # <--- not using f anymore...

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(op1)
  print(y.eval())
```

the result is always `2.0` as expected.

Can someone please explain why the behavior is different in the second case, and how I could enforce the evaluation of `f` after `x` has been updated in the first case?

Comment: I always get `4` in your first example on my machine `tensorflow=1.12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that `f` is computed after the first assignment has taken place. So:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(0.0)

op0 = tf.assign_add(x, 1.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([op0]):
  f = x * x 
op1 = tf.assign(y, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(op1)
  print(y.eval())
  # 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution is certainly correct, but unfortunately I do not know the definition of `f` in my application. It is given as an input, so I cannot (re)define it.

Comment: @cthl I see... The problem is, if `f` was defined before `op0`, there is no good way to force it to run after it... You can just call `run` with `op0` first and then with `op1`, or _maybe_ you could ensure the workflow with something like [`partial_run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#partial_run) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I do not have have any influence on how `run()` is called in my application. In fact, I just construct a list of ops that are run elsewhere. That is why I am so focused on `control_dependencies()`. I found a solution for my specific problem (see below). I will still accept your answer as the solution, as it answers my original question and because it is probably what people are looking for when reading this in the future.

Comment: @cthl Thank you, I'm glad you found a solution, I think it's good, as `tf.gradients` creates new operations that will have to run after the assignment. Feel free to leave whichever answer you prefer marked as accepted.

Comment: Hi,@jdehesa. Is your result `1.0` or `4.0` in first example? It's strange that I always get `4.0`.

Comment: @giser_yugang I get `1.0` some times when I run on CPU, on GPU I seem to get `4.0` always (TF 1.12).

Comment: @jdehesa Oh, I see. Can you explain the difference with GPU and CPU?

Comment: @giser_yugang Not really, I'm afraid. I mean, I suppose the scheduling of operations may be different for CPU and GPU? And there are different kinds of overhead when working with the GPU (GPU memory access, startup, ...) that may "tip the balance" for good... But that's just guessing, I don't know specifics, really.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you anyway. That's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. In my application I actually evaluate the gradient of `f`, not `f` itself, so the following seems to work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.Variable(0.0)
f = x*x
df = tf.gradients(f, x)[0]

op0 = tf.assign_add(x, 1.0)
with tf.control_dependencies([op0]):
  #op1 = tf.assign(y, df) <--- does not work
  df_new = tf.gradients(f, x)[0]
  op1 = tf.assign(y, df_new) # <--- seems to work

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(op1)
  print(y.eval())
```